# In Ohio, If someone has a personal lock which needs to be opened for which they have lost the key, is it illegal to possess lock picking tools?

Tags: ohio

For easier reference, here is Ohio law on the subject:

https://law.justia.com/codes/ohio/2011/title29/chapter2923/section2923-24/

It would appear to violate B2, but I am curious how a locksmith would operate legally under the same conditions.

Answer (score 5):

Note that an essential element of the offense here is "**with purpose to use it criminally.**"

The specifications in B allow a presumption of such purpose, but such a presumption is rebuttable.

The tools of a locksmith are somewhat different from those of a criminal "cracksman", I understand, and would probably not be considered "designed or specially adapted for criminal use". But even if they were, proof of regular employment as a locksmith would tend to rebut the presumption of criminal intent.

Possession of tools with the intent of lawfully opening one's own lock would not be criminal intent, but a judge or jury might not be convinced of that.